# Fully configurable pages with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack

My project has a particular use-case which I am not sure how to configure using Webpack 4.

In my application, pages are composed by the server at runtime, based on configuratin. 
As a result, I do not know which bundles will be required until the server actually gets a request and selects them.

Essentially, there are two kinds of modules that make up my app:

1. **Library modules**: these are some utility modules for my app. All pages created will require these.
   E.g. Ajax sender, sorting and searching, etc.
2. **Generic modules**: these are the modules which the server selects based on the page's configuration. 
   E.g. chat feature, ads popup, data table, etc.

Note that I am the maintainer for both these kinds of modules, so I have full flexibility on how to structure them. 
**Vendor modules** are mainatined by third-parties (e.g. jQuery).

Generic modules depend on Library modules, but not vice-verca. Generic modules do not have dependencies on each other.

Folder structuring of application:

```
app-root/
    - libs/*.js
    - generics/*.js
```

My application request flow looks like this:
1. Server gets a request for a particular page configuration. It determines that it needs Generic modules X, Y, Z to satisfy this configuration.
2. Server creates `<script>` tags to serve all Library modules at once (`my-libs.bundle.js`). 
3. Server creates a separate `<script>` tag for each Generic module (`A.bundle.js`, `B.bundle.js`, etc).

How do I set up Webpack to generate the bundles in this way?

---

#### Current progress using Webpack 4:

1. Entry points: all modules are entry points.

   ```
   entry: ['libs/*.js', 'generics/*.js']
   ```
2. Cache groups:

   ```
   optimization: {
       splitChunks: {
           cacheGroups: [
               {
                   test: /libs\/*.js/,
                   chunks: "normal",
                   name: "libs",
                   enforce: true
               },
               {
                   test: /generics\/A.js/,
                   chunks: "normal",
                   name: "A",
                   enforce: true
               },
               {
                   test: /generics\/B.js/,
                   chunks: "normal",
                   name: "B",
                   enforce: true
               },
               {
                   test: /generics\/C.js/,
                   chunks: "normal",
                   name: "C",
                   enforce: true
               },
               ...etc
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

   The Regex pattern matching may not be perfect, but you get the idea.
3. Output:

   ```
   output: {
       filename: '[name].bundle.js',
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/js')
   },
   ```

---

#### Problems faced:

When I run the above setup I get the following bundles:
1. `main.bundle.js`: contains Webpack runtime, list of modules (manifest?), etc.
2. `libs.bundle.js`
3. `A.bundle.js`
4. `B.bundle.js`
5. `C.bundle.js`
6. ...etc

So far, so good.

Now, I get my server to generate HTML pages in the following way (pseudocode):

```
<script src="build/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/libs.bundle.js"></script>

for (modulePath of requestedGenericModulePaths) {
    console.log(`<script src="${modulePath}"></script>`);
}

...
```

(Ignore syntax, CDN loading etc...this is just an example).

So if the request is for a page with Generic modules X and Y, the following HTML will be output:

```
<script src="build/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/libs.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="build/js/generics/X.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/generics/Y.bundle.js"></script>

...
```

So far, so good.

However, **this is where I am stuck**. The above HTML does not work; if I put logging statements in X and Y, they do not show on the browser console.

I looked into `main.bundle.js`. From what I understand, it seems like *ALL* generic modules are being required in `main.bundle.js`.

I am not sure how to proceed. Should I set `chunks: "async"` in each cacheGroup? Should I make all my generic modules externals? Should I play around with the Manifest?